# sbt-native-packager with Docker and Elastic Beanstalk congifuation

Tags: playframework, sbt, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt-native-packager to deploy my Playframework app to Elastic Beanstalk as a Docker container. It's all working pretty well, but I need to customize the ELB instance a bit. Amazon documents [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) that you do this by creating a `.config` file "in an `.ebextensions` top-level directory of your source bundle."

Seems simple enough, but I'm not sure what the best way to get sbt-native-packager to pick up my .ebextensions directory and put it in the right place. I know if I was creating the bundle using the command `docker build -t my-docker-app /my-project-root` I would stick the directory right under `my-project-root`, but I am confused by how things are bundled with native packager.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Docker Plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) uses the [Universal Plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html) under the hood.
So you can use the [default folder structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#customize) to simply add directories/files to your app.

```
src/universal/.ebextensions
```

This will result in an ouput directory structure like this

```
.ebextensions/
bin/
lib/
conf/
```

If this it not enough for you, you can always customize the `mappings in Docker` or `mappings in Universal` as described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#mappingshelper)